# incomplete \ifodd , all text was ignored... error

Tags: errors, equations

shall you please help me to know why here I have got an error ? :

```
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{3-6}
\begin{aligned}
\overline{\epsilon}_{ij}  = \frac{1}{V} \int_V \epsilon}_{ij} dV\\
\overline{\sigma}_{ij}  = \frac{1}{V} \int_V \sigma}_{ij} dV
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: missing `\documentclass`

Comment: @azetina Both the `_{...}` and the `^{...}` bits are optional after `\int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have opening braces missing in the right hand side of your equation.  Second, if you use `aligned`, you'd better provide `&` as alignment markers.

This works:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{3-6}
\begin{aligned}
\overline{\epsilon}_{ij}  &= \frac{1}{V} \int_V {\epsilon}_{ij} dV\\
\overline{\sigma}_{ij}  &= \frac{1}{V} \int_V {\sigma}_{ij} dV
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you ,so the class : amsart is obligatory to add, I add it to my settings as well? cause I don't have it in my code

Comment: this is how I used :

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

Comment: You need either `amsart` class or `\usepackage{amsmath}` to use `aligned`.

Comment: @Farzad64 The `amsart` class loads `amsmath`; with other classes you need `\usepackage{amsmath}`.